# Adjust the width of input field type text in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, inputfield, text

```html
<div>
<lightning-input type="datetime" name="input5" label="Start Date:" value={earliestDate} min={minEndDate} max={maxEndDate} onchange={handleDateChange} required></lightning-input>
</div>
<div>
    <lightning-input type="text" label="Comments" value={comments} onchange={handleCommentChange}></lightning-input>
</div>
```

For the comments, I get a very long text field. How can I control the size of the field, can I shorten it? There is nothing in the specification that talks about the width - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input/specification

Want the width only as highlighted in the image below:

[image]

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ordinarily, you'd use a grid to control the layout:

```
<lightning-layout multiple-rows>
  <lightning-layout-item size="4">
    <lightning-input type="datetime" name="input5" label="Start Date:" value={earliestDate} min={minEndDate} max={maxEndDate} onchange={handleDateChange} required></lightning-input>
  </lightning-layout-item>
  <lightning-layout-item size="8"><!-- skip to next row -->
  </lightning-layout-item>
  <lightning-layout-item size="4">
        <lightning-input type="text" label="Comments" value={comments} onchange={handleCommentChange}></lightning-input>
  </lightning-layout-item>
</lightning-layout>
```

That said, an overflow of the viewing area suggests that you have a parent element that's too wide; the default size of lightning-input is set to 100% of its parent component. You probably have other CSS or layout issues that will need to be fixed.

Comment: Thank you. I did something similar but my borders and alignment are off. Any idea what I can do to align the way I need? Added a separate question with the expectation  - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/382401/how-to-style-and-align-3-fields-in-lwc-component

Answer (score 0):

Add a css and resolved it:

```
.inputWidth{
    width: 450px;
}
```