# How to style and align 3 fields in LWC component

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, slds, slds-grid

```
<template>
    <lightning-card
    title="Update Service Appointment Earliest Start Time"
    icon-name="utility:date_time"
    >
    <span>
        <div class="slds-grid">
            <div class="slds-col">
                <lightning-input type="datetime" class="earlyDateClass" name="earlDate" label="Earliest Start Date:" value={earliestDate} min={minDate} max={maxEndDate} onchange={handleDateChange} required></lightning-input>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-col">
                Service Appointment Due Date: {maxEndDate}
            </div>
            <div class="slds-col">
                <lightning-input type="text" label="Comments:"  placeholder="Enter message here for chatter post" value={comments} onchange={handleCommentChange}></lightning-input>
            </div>
        </div>   
    </span>
    <div class="slds-grid slds-docked-form-footer slds-m-right_large">
    <lightning-button
        class="slds-m-top_small"
        variant="brand"
        type="submit"
        name="save"
        label="Save"
        onclick={handleSave}
        disabled={disableButton}
    >
    </lightning-button>
    </div>
</lightning-card>
</template>
```

What I get is:

[image]

How do I make them appear in the same row? And little space from the border so that it is aligned a little right. How can this be achieved with grid. Any suggestions. What I am looking for is:

[image]

ANother approach I tried is:

```
<span><!--
    <div class="slds-grid">
        <div class="slds-col">
            <lightning-input type="datetime" class="earlyDateClass" name="earlDate" label="Earliest Start Date:" value={earliestDate} min={minDate} max={maxEndDate} onchange={handleDateChange} required></lightning-input>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-col">
            Service Appointment Due Date: {maxEndDate}
        </div>
        <div class="slds-col">
            <lightning-input type="text" label="Comments:"  placeholder="Enter message here for chatter post" value={comments} onchange={handleCommentChange}></lightning-input>
        </div>
    </div>
-->
Due Date : 
    <lightning-formatted-date-time label="Service Appointment Due Date:" value={maxEndDate} year="numeric" month="numeric" day="numeric" hour="2-digit"
                                    minute="2-digit"></lightning-formatted-date-time>
<lightning-layout multiple-rows>
    <lightning-layout-item size="4">
        <lightning-input type="datetime" class="earlyDateClass" name="earlDate" label="Earliest Start Date:" value={earliestDate} min={minDate} max={maxEndDate} onchange={handleDateChange} required></lightning-input>
    </lightning-layout-item>
    <lightning-layout-item size="8">
    </lightning-layout-item>
    <lightning-layout-item size="6">
        <lightning-input type="text" label="Comments:"  placeholder="Enter message here to post to chatter" value={comments} onchange={handleCommentChange}></lightning-input>
    </lightning-layout-item>
  </lightning-layout>
</span>
```

This gave me:

[image]

BUT, there is no space between the borders. Is there a way to add a little space and make this look more better? Is this the right approach?  How can I make comments label bold , similar to the label of date&time field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have use the size of the grid as well as explained in the [documentation](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/grid/). To add space use [padding](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/padding/), as needed. To make the label bold, use the variant attribute to hide the label and create your own label for the component.

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Update Service Appointment Earliest Start Time" icon-name="utility:date_time">
        <div class="slds-p-left_medium slds-p-top_large">
            Service Appointment Due Date: 2022-09-01
        </div> 
        <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-p-around_medium">           
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_2-of-6">
                <lightning-input type="datetime" class="" name="earlDate" label="Earliest Start Date:"
                    value={earliestDate} min={minDate} max={maxEndDate} onchange={handleDateChange} required>
                </lightning-input>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_4-of-6"></div>
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                <legend class="slds-form-element__legend slds-form-element__label">Comments:</legend>
                <lightning-input type="text" variant="label-hidden" placeholder="Enter message here for chatter post"
                    value={comments} onchange={handleCommentChange}></lightning-input>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2"></div>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

[image]